# About assembler far calls and the heaven's gate, do segment calls that trigger an exception push cs and eip BEFORE the exception is thrown?

Tags: windows, assembly, wow64, seh, fasm

Currently i'm playing with the windows/WOW64 trick known as "the heaven's gate", which, as some of you will probably know, allows us to enter x64 mode even though in a x86 program (i was so amazed when i tested it and it worked!) But i know it is not supported on all Windows versions, so my code (because there is a code) uses seh, it looks like this:

```
start:
  use32
  ;; setup seh...
  call $33:.64bits_code ; specify 0x33 segment, it's that easy
  ;; success in x64 mode, quit seh...
  jmp .exit

.64bits_code:
  use64
  ;; ...
  use32
  retf

.seh_handler:
  use32
  ;; ...
  xor eax,eax ; EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION
  ret

.32bits_code: 
  ; we have been called by a far call (well, indirectly, routed by a seh handler)
  ; HERE IS THE PROBLEM => Should i use a retf since cs and eip are on the stack, 
  ;                        or the exception has been triggered before pushing them???
  ; "retf" or "jmp .exit"?

.exit:
  xor eax,eax
  push eax
  call [ExitProcess]
```

I know a simple "jmp .exit" would do the trick, but i'm terribly curious about it

Comment: What is your question?  If it's that comment in the code, please make it part of your question proper.

Comment: I'm so sorry, this is my first StackOverflow question. Well, yes, my question is: if an exception is triggered (for example, if the code runs in an x86 only system), will cs and eip have been already pushed on the stack? therefore, should i retf, or simply jmp?

Answer (score 1):

When the OS gets an interrupt or a fault happens, it expects that no matter what the user code was up to, the CPU has saved the required state on the kernel stack so that an `IRET` will invisibly resume whatever it was doing.

Note that there is no "magic" involved in that state on the kernel stack. "Continuing execution" only means restoring saved values of `rflags`, `cs:rip` and `ss:rsp` and running the code that `cs:rip` ends up pointing to.

That means that without involving SEH specifically, just thinking about any kind of exception happening during a far call, there are really only two cases to consider:

1. The exception happens "before" the jump: nothing has been pushed, the state on the kernel stack says we should resume by restarting the call instruction.
2. The exception happens "after" the jump: `cs:eip` have been pushed, `rip` points somewhere at or after the `.64bits_code` label, and that saved state says that to resume we should jump to the 64-bit code.

If the CPU allowed a far call to be interrupted "in the middle", there would be no possible value of `cs:rip` that produces a consistent result when the OS continues execution. For example, if the far call's return address was pushed before the exception happened but the saved `cs:rip` points to the far call instruction, you'll end up with *two* copies of the return address on the stack and all hell breaks loose.

Now, to actually answer your question: it depends on the value of rIP that the OS tells you the exception happened on. If it points to the 64-bit code you must have cs:eip on the stack, if it points to the 32-bit code you can safely assume it has not been pushed yet.